# XSLT bug in Firefox?

Tags: xml, firefox, xslt, html-table

So I have an XML document that describes a table like this

```
<Section Columns="1" Id="2" Name="DataTable">
    <DataTable Name="TestDataTable">
      <DisplayOptions Column="1" />
      <TableOptions Appendable="true" />
      <Header Name="tableHeader">
        <Label isCurrency="false">Unit</Label>
        <Label isCurrency="false">type</Label>
        <Label isCurrency="false">Min</Label>
        <Label isCurrency="false">Max</Label>
        .... more label for the header
      </Header>           
      <Row>
        <Label>A unit</Label>
        <DataField Id="312" Name="unit1" ControlType="Text">                         
          <FieldOptions Visibility="true" isCurrency="false"/> 
        </DataField>
        .... more datafield
      </Row>
      ... more rows
      <footer  name="tableFooter">
        <Label>Total # of Units:</Label>
        <Label>0</Label>
        ... more label
      </footer>
```

and an XSLT stylesheet that uses that XML to create a table using HTML, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="Header">
<thead>
  <xsl:for-each select="Label">
    <th class="dataTableHeader">
      <xsl:variable name="currentPosition" select="position() - 1"/>
      <label>
        <xsl:value-of select="self::node()"/>
      </label>
    </th>
  </xsl:for-each>
</thead>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="footer">
<tfoot>
  <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="Label">
    <th class="dataTableFooter">
      <xsl:variable name="currentPosition" select="position() - 1"/>
      <label name="Silly">
        <xsl:value-of select="self::node()"/>
      </label>
    </th>
  </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>    
</tfoot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Row">
<tr class="tableRow">
  <!-- apply the template flag if it is there -->
  <xsl:if test="@Template = 'true'">
    <xsl:attribute name="data-is-template" />
  </xsl:if>
  <!-- there should only be one label in each row -->
  <xsl:if test="Label">
    <td class="dataTableRowTitle">
      <label for="{DataField[1]/@Id}">
        <xsl:value-of select="Label"/>
      </label>
    </td>
  </xsl:if>
  <!-- apply the datafield templates in table mode -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="DataField" mode="tableInput" />
</tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Label">
<xsl:value-of select="self::text()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that the XSLT is rendering the tfooter as a row of the tbody as oppose to making it separate. I checked the html and the tfooter is a child of the tbody. This only happens in Firefox; it works great in all other major broswers.

```
<td colspan="2">
    <table class="dataTable">         
      <thead>...</thead>            
      <tbody>
          <tr class="tableRow"></tr>
          <tr class="tableRow"></tr>
          <tr class="tableRow"></tr>
          <tr class="tableRow"></tr>                  
          <tfoot>...</tfoot>
      </tbody> 
    </table>
</td>
```

When I check the other browsers, I find that tfooter is a sibling of tbody and theader.

```
<td colspan="2">
    <table class="dataTable">         
      <thead>...</thead>                     
      <tbody>
          <tr class="tableRow"></tr>
          <tr class="tableRow"></tr>
          <tr class="tableRow"></tr>
          <tr class="tableRow"></tr>                               
      </tbody> 
      <tfoot>...</tfoot>
    </table>
</td>
```

So I moved the footer part in the XML to between the Header and the Row and now it works. The tfooter is now a sibling of tbody and theader, and is before tbody.

```
 <td colspan="2">
    <table class="dataTable">         
      <thead>...</thead> 
      <tfoot>...</tfoot>           
      <tbody>
          <tr class="tableRow"></tr>
          <tr class="tableRow"></tr>
          <tr class="tableRow"></tr>
          <tr class="tableRow"></tr>                               
      </tbody> 
    </table>
</td>
```

So the question is why did Firefox do that? Is it a bug or is it that Firefox renders the header and footer first before the the row when creating a table, so we have to process the header and footer first in the XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are probably looking at is HTML based on the resultant DOM from the XML that is generated by the XSLT. Its important to recognise that the source of a document may be altered when viewing the DOM, which is usually what you see in developer tools like Firefox's Firebug or IE's F12.

For example, what you are looking at might be the last step in this:

```
Input XML --[ XSLT ]--> Output HTML --[ Browser API ]--> Resultant DOM
```

If you look at the [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3), the `<tfoot>` element must come *before* the `<tbody>`, not after. [The restriction was changed in HTML5](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-tfoot-element) and the footer can come before or after the body, but its likely when creating the DOM from the HTML document Mozilla follows the old rules as its valid. The [Mozilla Developers Network page on `<tfoot>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tfoot) has some more info on this which is where I got some of the links.